# Downloading Streams Simulatenously with Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT: I think I've figured out a solution using subprocess.Popen with separate .py files for each stream being monitored. It's not pretty, but it works.

I'm working on a script to monitor a streaming site for several different accounts and to record when they are online. I am using the livestreamer package for downloading a stream when it comes online, but the problem is that the program will only record one stream at a time. I have the program loop through a list and if a stream is online, start recording with subprocess.call(["livestreamer"... The problem is that once the program starts recording, it stops going through the loop and doesn't check or record any of the other livestreams. I've tried using Process and Thread, but none of these seem to work. Any ideas?

Code below. Asterisks are not literally part of code.

`import os,urllib.request,time,subprocess,datetime,random
status = {
    "********":False,
    "********":False,
    "********":False
}
def gen_name(tag):
    return stuff <<Bunch of unimportant code stuff here.
def dl(tag):
    subprocess.call(["livestreamer","********.com/"+tag,"best","-o",".\\tmp\\"+gen_name(tag)])
def loopCheck():
    while True:
        for tag in status:
            data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://*******.com/" + tag + "/").read().decode()
            if data.find(".m3u8") != -1:
                print(tag + " is online!")
                if status[tag] == False:
                    status[tag] = True
                    dl(tag)
            else:
                print(tag+ " is offline.")
                status[tag] = False
        time.sleep(15)
loopCheck()`

Comment: Add the code you tried, also `call` blocks.

Comment: An idea: use asyncio, new in 3.4, with an adaptation of the code in livesteamer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've tried coroutines to no avail.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I've tried asyncio with my code and I wouldn't know how to rewrite the livestreamer package.

Comment: @person812949212442, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32161582/2141635

Comment: There is also a python api for livestreamer http://docs.livestreamer.io/api_guide.html#api-guide